# comma at the end of a dictionary - swift

Tags: xcode, dictionary, swift

Example code:

```
let interestingNumbers = [
    "Prime":[2,3,5,7,11,13],
    "Fibonacci":[1,1,2,3,5,8],
    "Square":[1,4,9,16,25]`,`
]
```

Question: after "Square:[1,4,9,16,25]", there is a comma(sample code from Apple Swift reference guide book), when I get rid of it, I didn't get any error messages from Xcode, is this just convention at all ? (I remember there is a `nil` after array or dictionary in objective-C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because a comma after the last element in a dictionary is optional.

Consider the simpler example:

```
let letters = ["A":1,
               "B":2,
               "C":3
]
```

A comma placed after the last element, `"C":3`, is acceptable, but optional.

I believe that there is no specific convention regarding the final comma - some may prefer it as it allows you to add items on following lines without modifying the above line to add the comma (makes source control review simpler). I often leave commas on the last element in an `enum` declaration for the same reason.

If you know you are likely to add more elements in the future, then having the comma would simplify the source diff in a code review (one added line instead of one removed line and two added lines). I would use the comma where you know you're going to add elements later, and omit in if the list of items is final.

Comment: Added a note about convention and why you might or might not use it

Comment: It's annoying that Xcode screws up the `]` indentation when using comma